# Issue with delegate return type

Tags: .net, reflection, delegates, .net-2.0

Have following code

```
public delegate object ParseHandler(string s);
public static ParseHandler GetParser(Type t)
{
    MethodInfo parse = t.GetMethod("Parse", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public,
        null, new Type[] { typeof(string) }, null);

    if (parse != null)
        return (ParseHandler)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(ParseHandler), parse, true);

    return null;
}
```

is blowing up on the `Delegate.CreateDelegate()` call with "Error binding to target method." apparently because `ParseHandler` is defined as returning `object` instead of type specific return value.

I don't know type at the compile type, so I can't replace `type` parameter with generic (and if I did then the whole function would not be needed).

A bit confused on how to deal with this. The required behavior is to find `public static Parse(string)` method for given type and create a delegate for it to be called later.

Comment: Are you strictly stuck on the .NET 2.0 platform?

Comment: Can you show us declaration of the `Parse` method that it is failing for?

Comment: Perhaps what you want to write is something like my `Parse<T>` https://github.com/CodeInChaos/ChaosUtil/blob/master/Chaos.Util/Conversion.cs except you'll probably need to replace some `T`s by object.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment yes.

Comment: @Ani take any integral type or `DateTime`

Comment: @CodeInChaos like I said I don't know the type at the compile time, so generic would be useless to me.

Comment: @liho1eye: Ah there you go; then Jon Skeet's answer is relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be fine so long as the real return value is a reference type - but it makes sense for this to fail for a value type return value. (See Eric Lippert's post about [representation and identity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx) for more detailed explanations.)

One option is to create a generic class like this:

```
public class BoxingParserDelegate<T>
{
    private readonly Converter<string, T> parser;

    public BoxingParserDelegate(Converter<string, T> parser)
    {
        this.parser = parser;
    }

    public object Parse(string x)
    {
        return parser(x);
    }
}
```

In your GetParser method, you'd check whether the return type of `parse` is a value type, and if so create an instance of `BoxingParserDelegate<T>` via reflection. You can then create the `ParseHandler` instance from the Parse method of the `BoxingParserDelegate`.

This will all be frankly somewhat awkward, but should work. It feels like there should be a simpler approach, to be honest.

(On .NET 3.5 or higher I'd recommend using expression trees, but I've only just seen the .NET 2.0 tag.)

EDIT: Aha, have thought of slightly simpler approach:

```
public static ParseHandler BuildParseHandler<T>(Converter<string, T> converter)
{
    // Performs boxing automatically
    return delegate(string x) { return converter(x); }
}
```

This is *effectively* asking the compiler to do half of the above work for you. Then you just need to work out whether you need to call this, and do so with reflection if necessary. Something like this:

```
public static ParseHandler GetParser(Type t)
{
    MethodInfo parse = t.GetMethod("Parse",
        BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public,
        null, new Type[] { typeof(string) }, null);

    // Method not found
    if (parse == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    // Reference type - use delegate covariance
    if (!parse.ReturnType.IsValueType)
    {
        return (ParseHandler) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(ParseHandler),
            parse, true);
    }

    // Tricky situation: call BuildParseHandler with generics
    Type delegateType = typeof(Converter<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(string),
                                                             parse.ReturnType);
    object converter = Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateType, parse, true);

    // You may need extra work to get this... let me know whether or not it works.
    // Obviously if you make it private, you'll need extra binding flags.
    MethodInfo method = typeof(TypeContainingThisMethod)
                            .GetMethod("BuildParseHandler");
    method = method.MakeGenericMethod(parse.ReturnType);

    return (ParseHandler) method.Invoke(null, new object[] { converter });
}
```

Comment: This is fine, but I would suggest using `Converter<string, T>` instead; the OP is on .NET 2.

Comment: unless I am missing something here, this comes down to creating instance of the `Func<string, T> parser`, which is exactly what my issue is in the first place. I can't have T as generic.

Comment: @liho1eye: Yes you can - you just need to do *that* part with generics. I'm keeping your *nongeneric* API (in that you'll return a ParseHandler) but you'll use generics via reflection in your method.

Comment: @Jon I am still confused... How do I get from instance of `MethodInfo` to `BuildParseHandler<MethodInfo.ReturnType>` ?

Comment: @liho1eye: Edited now, but I'm going to need to get the kids ready for bed, so it'll be a while before I can respond again.